# What is the best way to pass a list to javascript with Jinja2 without mixing the html and js code?

Tags: javascript, html, jinja2

I am using Jinja2 for making templates, and from what I have seen in other questions, I can pass a list to the template using the {{x}} notation. My problem is, wouldn't that mean that I would have Javascript code in the HTML template?

From what I understand it is better to separate the scripts from the HTML, and just call the scripts before closing the body tag. If I do something like what I wrote first, that wouldn't be the case, as seen in the example below.

```
<body>
(Other page elements)
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test_func(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
    test_func({{ data|safe }}) <-- MyList
</script>
</body>
```

In this case I would have some javascript in my html template, which as I understand is not optimal. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data could be loaded from an endpoint through AJAX or stored in your DOM.

Either using a  tag and the `window` object if you expect to use it in multiple places in your application and have no problems with polluting the global namespace

```
<script>
   window.myInitData = {{{myJSdata}}};
</script>
```

or on a DOM element

```
<div data-data={{{myJSData}}}></div>
```

which you'd then query for

```
var data = document.querySelector('yo').dataset.data;
test_func(data);
```

Now addressing your question about "storing JavaScript code in your HTML" for sure, you would not like to embed the JavaScript like that unless you're doing tracking or loading of external scripts. However storing data in the DOM would be considered fine, normally, and the upshot of doing the storing in `data` attributes is that scripts loaded through your normal script tags would get access to your data by querying for it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just one more thing, are both ways equivalent? Or do I have to take something else into consideration before choosing one or the other? In the first case, would it be the same to specify var = {{myJSdata}} instead of window.myInitData = {{myJSdata}}?

Comment: I would refrain from doing the `window` approach, just to keep the global state clean. And, yes, it's the same.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that.